# Drupal 8 : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

Please let me know , why my query return this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Here is my query :

```
 $result = $db->query('SELECT   CODE,  ID,  ORIGINAL_TITLE  ,  DESCRIPTION_EN   FROM {mapCSV_data}   WHERE  csv_data_status = 1 GROUP BY CODE ORDER BY CODE');
```

Thanks In Advance.
Deepak Goud

Comment: Because its syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Please let me know where?

Comment: Here is my full code : $db = \Drupal::database();  
         $result = $db->query('SELECT   CODE,  ID,  ORIGINAL_TITLE  ,  DESCRIPTION_EN   FROM {mapCSV_data}   WHERE  csv_data_status = 1 GROUP BY CODE');
         $result = $result->fetchAll();